# 'QtConcurrentRun': No such file or directory

Tags: qt

I am building a Qt project using Qt6.3.1. This project was originally written in earlier version of Qt (not quite sure about the specific version). Many Qt functions or modules need to be updated. It is noted `QtConcurrentRun` is noted supported by the recent Qt, since `#include <QtConcurrentRun>` gives the error: `'QtConcurrentRun': No such file or directory`.

I was wondering what module in Qt 6 is equivalent to [QtConcurrentRun](https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/html/qtconcurrentrun.html#details). Is that `QtConcurrent`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include QtConcurrent into the header file:

```
#include <QtConcurrent>
```

Add this line to your .pro file:

```
QT += concurrent
```

Then you may call the `run` function:

```
QtConcurrent::run(QThreadPool::globalInstance(), function, ...);
```

If it doesn't work for you take a look at the `QThread` class.

More info here: [QtConcurrent (Qt 6)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtconcurrent.html)